# Users should receive a warning before they're banned from asking questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-accounts

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

My Programmers account was banned recently from asking questions with only two questions raised, one get downvote to -1, and the other downvote to -4.

I think it is not so fair to the new user was banned for only asking 2 questions.

Do you think it is better to give a warning message before banning the account such that a user can seriously ask their questions later on?

Now that my account has been banned, I don't know what I can do in here anymore. :(

Answer (score 7):

There are actually four questions on your account. All of them have been closed and two have been deleted by you. At the time of this writing, one is at 0 score, and the rest are at -1, -4, and -5.

The exact details of the banning algorithm are not public, but [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998) on Meta Stack Overflow suggests a couple ways to potentially undo the ban. The gist of it is that you can still use the site and provide answers. If you focus on giving good answers that receive upvotes, your account may get unblocked and you will be able to ask questions again.

I don't know for sure how the algorithm works, but I think you may have tripped it just slightly, since your deleted questions are self-deleted and out of the two that remained visible one was closed as a duplicate after being migrated to us. You can try emailing team@stackoverflow.com and make your case for why your account should not have been banned. Be prepared to justify your request. No promises that it'll work for sure, but it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: Could you please add some advice for avoiding "further damages" from those downvoted questions? That is, a new user might start improving the situation by providing good answers; but the continuing of down-votes on those old questions might negate any gains from the that effort.

Comment: Questions with the score of -4 or lower are not shown on the front page, so they are more difficult to find and typically do not continue receiving downvotes. I don't have much data to support this, but in my experience, questions on main sites don't tend to get badly downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: One thing to potentially do is edit the question to improve it. If the question is closed, a good edit can help get it reopened. Beyond that, there's not much to do other than provide good answers and ask better questions in the future.